# Significance of two processes have same quadratic variation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I cant find info on the implications of two processes having same quadratic variation with any other procsses(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation)

i.e that $[M,N]=[P,N]$ for all say continuous semi martingales $N$. Intuitively speaking it looks like that two such processes show have same sizes of difference at the same spots and thus should be very "similar"

Anyone has a nice summary of this or a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapter IV.1 of Revuz and Yor's *Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion*, 3rd ed., provides a nice answer. Proposition 1.12 says that for a continuous local martingale $M$,

> $\langle M,M \rangle = 0$ if and only if $M$ is constant, that is $M_t = M_0$ a.s. for every $t$.

Thus, if $M$ and $P$ are both continuous local martingales, then choosing $N = M-P$ in your equation yields $[M-P,M-P] = 0$ so that $M$ and $P$ are the same up to a constant. If $M$ and $P$ are instead continuous semimartingales, then they are the same up to a process which is continuous, adapted, and of finite variation (meaning the total variation is finite over every interval $[0,t]$). In other words, their "continuous martingale parts" are the same up to a constant.